# map www.abc.com to www.t.xyz.com using cNAme

Tags: cname-record

I have a parent domain as www.xyz.com and a sub domain www.t.xyz.com

the site is hosted on www.t.xyz.com

I have another domain www.abc.com

**i want to map the www.abc.com to the sub domain www.t.xyz.com**

is this possible.

Comment: Can you clarify what problems you're seeing?  This is exactly what a `CNAME` record *does* - unless you're looking for it to do an HTTP redirect instead?

Comment: i am looking out for domain masking

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

Create a `CNAME` or `A` record for `www.abc.com` that points to the `www.t.xyz.com` (or it's IP address).

On the `www.t.xyz.com` server create a virtual host for `www.abc.com`. As you didn't say which webserver you're using we can't be much more specific than that.

Comment: I have hosting on www.xyz.com which allows me to have multiple subdomain on which the site content can be served. And i want to have www.abc.com to pull data from t.xyz.com,am i clear now

Comment: could you please elaborate more on your solution

Comment: If your website www.t.xyz.com is sharing an IP address and/or the web server uses the host name to figure out what site to serve, you must also configure the web server to recognize www.abc.com as an alias for www.t.xyz.com.